# Update multiple rows with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these 3 tables

Table books (i want to fill categories column with 1 string of categories delimited with a comma)

```
id      categories
1       null
2       null
3       null
...     ...
```

Table categories

```
id      name
1       adventure
2       horror
...     ...
```

Table BooksCategories (a book can have multiple categories)

```
bookid    categoryid
1         1
1         3
2         2
3         1
3         2
...       ...
```

I have a query that gives me something like this

```
bookid      categories
1           horror, adventure
2           action,...,...
```

Now, I want to update the column categories of my books table to the corresponding value of my query. Is it possible to do that in an update?

Thanks, I hope it is clear enough

Comment: Please re-consider your design: what you want to achieve is a presentation layer that could - and should, in most cases - be computed at runtime, or in specific views. Don't store redundant, consistance-dangerous data: you will then need quite a lot of triggering to keep the "categories" column up do date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `JOIN` your query with table `books` so you can update the column,

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.categories = b.categories
FROM    books a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            -- paste your query here
            -- SELECT   bookid, categories,.....
        ) b ON  a.id = b.bookid
```